# Symfony 2.7: Access not rendered property within the form-object

Tags: symfony, symfony-forms

I need access to a property within the form object. The Problem is, that the property I want to access is not rendered in the form and not declared in the contractType class.

```
    class ContractType extends AbstractType
    {
        /**
         * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
         * @param array $options
         */
        public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
        {
            $builder
                ->add('rcode1', new TextType(), array('label' => 'rcode 1'))
                ->add('rcode2', new TextType(), array('label' => 'rcode 2'));
        }
...
}
```

**Dump form object:**

```
array:6 [▼
  "contract" => Contract {#2003 ▼

    - id: null
    - actionCode: "104"
    - productCode: "20106"
    - created: null
    - updated: null
    - resumeId: null
    - rcode1: null
    - rcode2: null
    - downloadId: null
    - businessContractDetails: BusinessContractDetails {#1999 ▶}
    - privateContractDetails: null
    - company: Company {#2000 ▶}
    - persons: ArrayCollection {#1998 ▶}
  }

"businessContractDetails" => BusinessContractDetails {#1999 ▶}

"company" => Company {#2000 ▶}

"contactPerson" => ContactPerson {#1987 ▶}

"landlord" => Landlord {#1993 ▶}

"businessRealEstate" => BusinessRealEstate {#1994 ▶}

]
```

The properties that are rendered of the contract entity are rcode1 and rcode2. But I need access to downloadID.

I tried

```
$form->get('contract')->get('downloadId')->getData();
```

and got the following error message: *Child "downloadId" does not exist.*

Any suggestions? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
$form->get('contract')->getData()->getDownloadId();
```

Please note I'm assuming you have a getter `getDownloadId` in your `Contract` class

Comment: Sorry, I have less than 15 reputation points. I can't upvote your answer :(

Answer (score 0):

Your controller should not access the value of an entity via the form. It will work, but that's a bad practice, for example if the name of form type `contract` would change.

You can rely on the entity you create the form with, after `handleRequest` that entity is filled with the data from the form. So:

```
# Controller POST action
$entity = new Contract(); // Or retrieve it from database: $em->find(Contract, $id);
$form = $this->createForm(FormType::class, $entity)->handleRequest($request);
echo $entity->getDownloadId();
```